# How to use `patchcmd` with a code containing `{`?

Tags: macros, patching

I have a macro with a long `hbox`, and I'd like to integrate a simple `tikz` box by adding a line of code in front of its `{`. However, I'm facing challenges due to the inclusion of curly braces in that line. Here's a (MWE) to illustrate, I need to replace `\hbox{%` with `\hbox{\tikz[anchor=base,baseline]\node[red] at (0,0) {Tikz};%`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\text{\hbox{% 
This is a test.
%several lines of code here
}}


\patchcmd{\text}{\hbox{%
}
{\hbox{\tikz[anchor=base,baseline]\node[red] at (0,0) {Tikz};%
}
{\typeout{SUCCEEDED}}{\typeout{FAILED}}

\begin{document}
\text
\end{document}
```

While I'm aware that I can use the entire `\hbox{}` structure for patching, I find it cumbersome to repeat a substantial portion of code for a single-line modification. Specifically, I'm looking for a more concise approach to achieve this.

Comment: If you have control over the definition of `\text` you can do `\def\text{\hbox{\mycode This is a test.}}`, then define `\mycode` accordingly and save the trouble

Comment: why can't you put the \tikz simply before the \hbox?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It was just an example. But in reality, I wanted its width to be computed with the content of the box.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik No I don't have any control over it, as it is defined as an internal macro inside an external package used by my document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You definitely can't do it with `\patchcmd`.

Not that I recommend this, but, hey, it works!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\def\mytext{%
  \hbox{%
    This is a test.%
    %several lines of code here
  }%
}

\regexpatchcmd{\mytext}
  {\c{hbox}\{}
  {\c{\hbox}\{\c{tikz}[anchor=base,baseline]\c{node}[red]\ at\ (0,0)\ {Tikz};}
  {\typeout{SUCCESS}}{\typeout{FAILURE}}

\begin{document}

\mytext

\end{document}
```

If you do `\show\mytext` after the patch you get

```
> \mytext=macro:
->\hbox {\tikz [anchor=base,baseline]\node [red] at (0,0) {Tikz};This is a test.}.
```

You can also save some hassle with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\def\mytext{%
  \hbox{%
    This is a test.%
    %several lines of code here
  }%
}

\def\tmp{\tikz[anchor=base,baseline]\node[red] at (0,0) {Tikz};}

\regexpatchcmd{\mytext}
  {\c{hbox}\{}
  {\0\u{tmp}}
  {\typeout{SUCCESS}}{\typeout{FAILURE}}

\begin{document}

\mytext

\show\mytext

\end{document}
```

Explanations:

1. `\c{hbox}` matches `\hbox`;
2. `\{` matches the brace;
3. `\0` stands for the match;
4. `\u{tmp}` is replaced with the contents of the macro `\tmp`.

Comment: Thanks, why `\{` does not work with `patchcmd`?

Comment: @javadr Why should it? `\{` is not a brace. You cannot have unbalanced token lists in the argument to a command. In a regex, `\{` *represents* a brace.

Comment: Got it. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can first define a command that adds stuff inside the `\hbox` and than replace `\hbox` with your custom command via patching:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\myhbox[1]{%
    \hbox{\tikz[anchor=base,baseline]\node[red] at (0,0) {Tikz};%
        #1%
    }%
}

\newcommand\mytext{%
    \hbox{% 
        This is a test.
        %several lines of code here
    }%
}

\patchcmd{\mytext}
    {\hbox}
    {\myhbox}
    {\typeout{SUCCEDED}}{\typeout{FAILED}}

\begin{document}
\mytext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice hack +1 ;D

Comment: I like the way you saw my question. You've approached my answer from the other point of view.

Comment: @javadr Yes, I would not consider this being a hack, but a workaround. Sometimes, you need to think "around the corner" (as we say in German). It should actually be quite a robust approach.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I didn't mean TeX/LaTeX hack. I've just used it informally. Could you let me know the expression you mentioned above in your language?

Comment: @javadr So, it is like a thought hack =) . The German expression "um die Ecke denken" means "to think outside the box; to think via another route to achieve the goal".

Comment: Great expression, I will try to apply it in my real life ;D. 
To be honest with you, I've used your approach in my code as it didn't rely on the other new package. I chose egreg answer as the best because he really answered the question but I think it was kinda XY problem. ;=)